# Jquery Hide works but slideup does not

Tags: jquery

Updated: Placed in the proper syntax as suggested, the below code now works!

I have a foreach generating rows of data inside a table.  Each  element has an id of rowX.  I want my javascript to "slideup" the row of data after the Delete has been clicked.

If I use hide(); this works fine, but slideup(); is not working.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a.delete").click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var platform_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var row = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "platform/delete",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'platform_id='+platform_id,
        success: function(result){
            if (result.success == 1)
            {
                $("#row" + row).slideUp('slow');
                //document.getElementById(row).style.display = 'none'
            }
        },
        error: function(result){
            alert(result.message);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$("#row" + row).slideUp('slow');  
// See the single qoutes here for slow effect
// Also `U` should be capital in slideUp
```

Instead of this:

```
$("#row" + row).slideup(slow);
```

Comment: Alright, now its working.  However, it just seems to be a timed hide function, I don't actually see any animation.  Is this perhaps a limitation of the CSS?  I am using a template found on themeforest.

Comment: Are you using the **hide()** & the **slideUp()** functions together? In order to see the slideUp animation don't use **hide()** function with it!

Comment: I am only using the slideUp.  However I changed it to fadeOut(); and it is giving me a result I want.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) says `slow` should be a string, i.e.

```
$("#row" + row).slideUp('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks, the 'slow' parameter was added in right before I tossed in this question, the real solution for me was the capital U - I did not realize they were case sensitive!  But you are also correct 'parameter' not parameter

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't spotted the casing problem